# Oracle insert from select into table with more columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to insert to a table from a select statement, however, there are 3 columns returned from the select statement and the table has 4 columns, I would like to add 0 for all rows in the extra column. Can anyone give me a sample SQL query for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Just add in the '0' in your select.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (a,b,c,d)
    SELECT
       other_table.a AS a,
       other_table.b AS b,
       other_table.c AS c,
       '0' AS d
    FROM other_table
```

Comment: +1 for a complete example, but includes more stuff than I would normally use. I would not have `()` around the `select` statement and would not alias the column names. I would leave the zero unquoted if the target column had a numeric type, quoting only if the target column had a character datatype.

Answer (score 5):

Put 0 as default in SQL or add 0 into your area of table

Answer (score 1):

just select '0' as the value for the desired column