# insert bulk data in single statement in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to insert bulk data (multiple rows) in single insert statement in oracle.
any help please?

insert into Test(C1,C2,C3) select (v1,v2,v3)from emp ;

Comment: Check this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842938/oracle-insert-from-select-into-table-with-more-columns

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that by an insert/select statement:

```
INSERT INTO TEST(C1, C2, C3)
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3
FROM EMP;
```

Just be sure the fields you're selecting match the type of the table you want to insert them into.