# Can I, and how to, query severals database schemas with IntelliJ database tool?

Tags: database, oracle, intellij-idea, liquibase

I'm using IntelliJ to create my application, and an Oracle Database.

At the moment, I have to migrate data from an older database `SCHEMA` to a newer one. Tables and columns changed, and I want to create a IQBase script, which will be run on the different server during installation of the new application version.

So I have got, data in the old `SCHEMA` (we will talk about `OLD_SCHEMA`) and I want to `SELECT` these data, transform them and `INSERT INTO` the `NEW_SCHEMA`. So I wanna do something like :

```
INSERT INTO NEW_SCHEMA.TABLE_X (........) SET (SELECT ..... FROM OLD_SCHEMA.TABLE_Y)
```

BUT When I'm trying to executing this kind of query in the database tool bundled with IntelliJ, I got an error explaining, that there is a non existing table or a view.

```
[2016-09-06 15:22:29] [42000][942] ORA-00942: Table ou vue inexistante
```

It seems normal, because, when I create a SQL console file to test my queries, it is linked to one of the two schema.

So, can I , and if I can, How to execute my queries to use data of the two schema ?

Thank you.

PS : An Import, export isn't the solution, the structure changed a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query tables in another schema, unless you have been given the right to do so. If you connect to new_schema and want to query old_schema.table_y you need select privileges on old_schema.table_y.

In order to do so connect to old_schema and grant these privileges.

```
grant select on table_y to new_schema;
```

Now your query should work (without the set statement).

See this link for a syntax example.
[Oracle insert from select into table with more columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842938/oracle-insert-from-select-into-table-with-more-columns)

Answer (score 2):

To work with two schemas your USER must have grants (on SELECT, INSERT, etc.) in both schemas.

Also you use wrong sintax for INSERT statement, you need use sintax like this

```
INSERT INTO NEW_SCHEMA.TABLE_X (........) SELECT ..... FROM OLD_SCHEMA.TABLE_Y
```

Comment: In fact, it seems, that it will be a bit harder than estimated : I want to insert old data in the new tables, but not entirely. Form example I want to generate a dynamic Id through a sequence, get one or two old data in the old table and add new data.... Have you got an idea ?

Comment: You can use sequence in SELECT statement, for example 
`SELECT NEW_SHEMA.my_sequence.nextval, column1, column2, ... FROM OLD_SCHEMA.TABLE_Y`

Comment: Voici à peu de chose ce que je souhaiterais faire : `INSERT INTO COM_ADDRESS (ADDRESS_ID, CREATED_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, ADDRESS_LIGNE_1, ADDRESS_LIGNE_2, ADDRESS_LIGNE_3, ADDRESS_LIGNE_4, ADDRESS_LIGNE_5, COUNTRY_CODE, ADDRESS_TYPE_ID, CP, LOCALITE)
    SELECT '', TO_TIMESTAMP('06-SEPT-16 00.00.00', 'DD-MM-YY HH.MI.SS'), CREATED_DATE, ADDRESS_LIGNE_1, ADDRESS_LIGNE_2, ADDRESS_LIGNE_3, ADDRESS_LIGNE_4, ADDRESS_LIGNE_5, COUNTRY_CODE, '1', SUBSTR(ADDRESS_LIGNE_6, 1,5) "CP", SUBSTR(ADDRESS_LIGNE_6,6) "LOCALITE" FROM SOCLE.ADDRESS;
 `

Comment: @jdelagorce  So what is the problem?